# Retrieve large clob data using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, clob

How to completely retrieve large clob data from a table using sqlplus to the stdout? There is a way to get it completely using language specific DB APIs. But when I try to get it using purely sqlplus, I've faced several problems such as,

- Output buffer is too small (4000 is max)
- Character string buffer too small

Since oracle clob fields can contain 4GB (max) of data, is there any correct way to get the complete data chunk using sqlplus? Can I download it as a file?

I hope that the question is clear. I prefer if I can do it without injecting PL/SQL procedures to the database.

Answer (score 14):

1) First table and clob.

```
create table large_clob(a clob);
insert into large_clob values( dbms_xmlgen.getXml('select * from dba_objects'));
```

2) Run code in sqlplus

```
set linesize 32767 long 2000000000 longchunksize 32767 PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF ECHO OFF TERMOUT OFF
Spool output_file.txt
  select a from large_clob;
spool off
```

Description of all variables is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm)

- `long 2000000000` - specifies how many bytes of CLOB to retrieve. (2gb is max)
- `linesize` size of line (32k is max). size of line. If line exceeds the size , the line will be wrapped to next row
- `longchunksize 32k` -  clob will be retrieved in chunks, where the chunk size is 32k
- `PAGESIZE 0` - disbale result page fomrationg
- `FEEDBACK,ECHO,TERMOUT` - disable all of this.
- `Spool` redirect output to output_file.txt

Comment: Is it limited to the 32767 character limit?

Comment: It is size limit for line in clob.If line is longer it will be splitted to two lines.
[SET System Variable Summary](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm)

Comment: When it split the line into two lines, it also add an additional new line also. The generated file contain the sql which I executed also. Other than those problems, it does what is expected. I recommend the usage of `set heading off` before using this.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: @ncfirth As far as I understood, what it simply does is redirecting the output of sqlplus terminal to a file.

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz As I noticed, clob data is separated to two lines even if it doesn't exceed the 32767 chunk size.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it. But in here data which can be retrieved is limited to the max value of VARCHAR2 (32767).

```
exec dbms_output.enable(32767);
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    data_buffer VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    SELECT '<BGN>' || CLOBDATA_VALUE || '<END>' into data_buffer 
    FROM DUMMY_TABLE
    WHERE ID='DUMMY_ID';
    dbms_output.put_line(data_buffer);
EXCEPTION
    when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('<BGN>no rows selected<END>');
END;
```

It prints the clob data **as it is** to the stdout.

**Explanation**

- Following two items increase the output buffer size of the sqlplus
  `exec dbms_output.enable(32767);`
  `set serveroutput on`
- What the script does is select the clob data in to a `VARCHAR2`
  variable and print it via `dbms_output.put_line()`. Whenever there is
  no data (`no_data_found` exception occurs), the exception will be
  handled and error message will be generated.