# spooling into a file the content of a variable

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a variable defined like
variable my_var clob;
Then, in the pl/sql block I have another clob variable, x.
At the end of the block, I have
:my_var := x;

Then after the block, I start to spool into a file some ommands.
That "x" variable contains multiple select statements.
I have:

SPOOL .....
PROMPT SELECT .... from ....
PROMPT /

PROMPT :my_var
PROMPT /

But this doesn't work.
So I need in my final file to have a list of sql commands. The first is specified in clear with that PROMPT, but after I want to have all the SELECT statements in the file, which are contained in the variable :my_Var.
How can I spool the content of :my_Var into the file?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippts. too hard to read

Comment: If you're trying to spool a large clob, see this similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49526111/retrieve-large-clob-data-using-sqlplus

Comment: And if it is varchar? Is it possible without an additional table?